# list item bullet points duplicated

Tags: html, css, list

I am building this simple form (took the code from here https://codepen.io/JeromeRenders/pen/EPNxPv ) but the bullet points end up being duplicated on my page. How come? Here following is the html for the form and the css I am using. Thank you. I also added JS because that is what is creating the li list.

```css
body fieldset {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 10px #29a329;
}

body.error {
  background: #f04000;
}

body.error fieldset {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 10px #bd3200;
}

ul.items {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: -60px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul.items li {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0.4;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.items li.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

form {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

form fieldset {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.2);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

form fieldset input,
form fieldset p {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

form fieldset p {
  margin-top: 22px;
  text-align: center;
}

form fieldset input {
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

body.error fieldset {
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  animation: error 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <ul class="items"></ul>
  <fieldset class="username enable">
    <div class="icon left"><i class="user"></i></div>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
    <div class="icon right button"><i class="arrow"></i></div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="email">
    <div class="icon left"><i class="letter"></i></div>
    <input type="mail" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <div class="icon right button"><i class="arrow"></i></div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="thanks">
    <div class="icon left"></div>
    <p>Thanks for your time</p>
    <div class="icon right"></div>
  </fieldset>
  </form>

JS

    function init() {
  // Generate li foreach fieldset
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var ul = document.querySelector('ul.items'),
    li = document.createElement("li");

    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
 // Add class active on first li
  ul.firstChild.classList.add('active');
}
```

Here is an image of what I get:
[Duplicated bullet points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGqK3.png)

Comment: It's fine with Chrome

Comment: I'm using Chrome!

Comment: In line 2 of your HTML you are opening and closing the `ul`. This might not fix the issue your seeing, your codepen works fine in Chrome for me as mentioned above too.

Comment: Could you edit the StackSnippet so that it shows the problem?

Comment: The CodePen isn't OPs code. _"took the code from here"_

Comment: @Turnip the code here we see nothing ..

Comment: Exactly. That's why I asked OP to edit it. :)

Comment: Personal opinion: Such every single field step-by-step forms that try to drag one piece of information out at a time, are annoying a/f. IMHO this is a typical case of a designer’s perspective massively colliding with proper UX. Gimmicky and nice to look at the first time maybe - but a huge p.i.t.a. to actually use. For example this doesn’t allow me to input the info in the order I have it available in (I might know what to input into most fields, but have to go look up f.e. a credit card number), it doesn’t provide a proper overview of the entirety of the entered data, etc.

Comment: @Turnip I can't edit it because it seems to only happen on my side. CBroe I see your point, I think you are right

Comment: You can see the problem very clearly in the photo I put at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Below code useful for that:
css:

```
body {
  background: #33cc33;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
body fieldset {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 10px #29a329;
}

body.error {
  background: #f04000;
}
body.error fieldset {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 10px #bd3200;
}

h1, h2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

h1 {
  top: 24px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
}

h2 {
  top: 44px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 10px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

ul.items {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: -60px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
ul.items li {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0.4;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul.items li.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

form {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
form fieldset {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.2);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
form fieldset input, form fieldset p {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
form fieldset p {
  margin-top: 22px;
  text-align: center;
}
form fieldset input {
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
form fieldset .icon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 15px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
form fieldset .icon i {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
form fieldset .icon i::before, form fieldset .icon i::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
}
form fieldset .icon.left {
  left: 10px;
}
form fieldset .icon.right {
  right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
form fieldset .icon.button:hover {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
form fieldset.enable {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0.2s;
  transform: scale(1);
  animation: enable 0.5s ease-out 0.2s;
}
form fieldset.disable {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  transform: translateY(120px) scale(0.9);
}

body.error fieldset {
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  animation: error 0.3s ease-out;
}

@keyframes enable {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.2);
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes error {
  0%, 50%, 100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(3deg);
  }
}
/**
 * Icons in CSS, long as f****
 */
.icon .arrow {
  width: 2px;
  height: 17px;
  top: 5px;
  left: 14px;
  background: #333333;
}
.icon .arrow::before {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: -3px;
  border-color: #333333;
  border-right: 2px solid;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.icon .user {
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #333333 inset;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 3px 3px;
}
.icon .user::before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: -9px;
  left: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #333333 inset;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.icon .letter {
  width: 20px;
  height: 12px;
  top: 9px;
  left: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #333333 inset;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.icon .letter::before, .icon .letter::after {
  width: 11px;
  height: 2px;
  top: 4px;
  background: #333333;
}
.icon .letter::before {
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
.icon .letter::after {
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

.icon .lock {
  width: 20px;
  height: 16px;
  top: 9px;
  left: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #333333 inset;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.icon .lock::before {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  top: -4px;
  left: 4px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-top: 2px solid #333333;
  border-right: 2px solid #333333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.icon .lock::after {
  width: 6px;
  height: 7px;
  top: 4px;
  left: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #333333 inset;
}

.icon .heart {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 11px;
  left: 7px;
  background: #ff5233;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.icon .heart::before, .icon .heart::after {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ff5233;
}
.icon .heart::before {
  left: -6px;
}
.icon .heart::after {
  top: -6px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form>
  <ul class="items"><li class="active"></li><li></li><li></li><li></li></ul>
  <fieldset class="username enable">
    <div class="icon left"><i class="user"></i></div>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
    <div class="icon right button"><i class="arrow"></i></div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="email">
    <div class="icon left"><i class="letter"></i></div>
    <input type="mail" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
    <div class="icon right button"><i class="arrow"></i></div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="password">
    <div class="icon left"><i class="lock"></i></div>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
    <div class="icon right button"><i class="arrow"></i></div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="thanks">
    <div class="icon left"><i class="heart"></i></div>
    <p>Thanks for your time</p>
    <div class="icon right"><i class="heart"></i></div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function init() {
  // Generate li foreach fieldset
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(1)){break;}
    var ul = document.querySelector('ul.items'),
        li = document.createElement("li");

    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
window.CP.exitedLoop(1);

  // Add class active on first li
  ul.firstChild.classList.add('active');
}

function next(target) {
  var input = target.previousElementSibling;

  // Check if input is empty
  if (input.value === '') {
    body.classList.add('error');
  } else {
    body.classList.remove('error');

    var enable = document.querySelector('form fieldset.enable'),
        nextEnable = enable.nextElementSibling;
    enable.classList.remove('enable');
    enable.classList.add('disable');
    nextEnable.classList.add('enable');

    // Switch active class on left list
    var active = document.querySelector('ul.items li.active'),
        nextActive = active.nextElementSibling;
    active.classList.remove('active');
    nextActive.classList.add('active');
  }
}

function keyDown(event) {
  var key = event.keyCode,
      target = document.querySelector('fieldset.enable .button');
  if (key == 13 || key == 9) next(target);
}

var body = document.querySelector('body'),
    form = document.querySelector('form'),
    count = form.querySelectorAll('fieldset').length;

window.onload = init;
document.body.onmouseup = function (event) {
    var target = event.target || event.toElement;
    if (target.classList.contains("button")) next(target);
};
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown, false);
```

Comment: @user9595485 that eliminates the bullets all together

Comment: @flowover9 How can check your problem because your StackSnippet code is not work. So I guess li default properties list-style-type is not problem that.